# How to make .bash_prompt change permanent

Tags: bash

I'm having difficulty setting my prompt correctly. At present, I have the following symlinks associated with dotfiles in my home directory. I assume I would need to souce `.bash_prompt` in order to make this change persist, but still nothing.

Am I linking in the wrong direction, perhaps?

`.bash_profile` `.bash_profile -> Documents/Dotfiles/.bash_profile`

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH

source ~/.bashrc

if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi

function http(){
  curl http://httpcode.info/$1;
}

alias fuck='eval $(thefuck $(fc -ln -1)); history -r'

complete -o "nospace" -W "Contacts Calendar Dock Finder Mail Safari iTunes SystemUIServer Terminal Twitter" killall;
```

`.bashrc`

`source .bash_prompt`

`.bash_prompt` `.bash_prompt -> Documents/Dotfiles/.bash_prompt`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Shell prompt based on the Solarized Dark theme.
# Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/EkEtphC.png
# Heavily inspired by @necolas’s prompt: https://github.com/necolas/dotfiles
# iTerm → Profiles → Text → use 13pt Monaco with 1.1 vertical spacing.

if infocmp xterm-256color >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    export TERM='xterm-256color';
fi;

prompt_git() {
    local s='';
    local branchName='';

    # Check if the current directory is in a Git repository.
    if [ $(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree &>/dev/null; echo "${?}") == '0' ]; then

        # check if the current directory is in .git before running git checks
        if [ "$(git rev-parse --is-inside-git-dir 2> /dev/null)" == 'false' ]; then

            # Ensure the index is up to date.
            git update-index --really-refresh -q &>/dev/null;

            # Check for uncommitted changes in the index.
            if ! $(git diff --quiet --ignore-submodules --cached); then
                s+='+';
            fi;

            # Check for unstaged changes.
            if ! $(git diff-files --quiet --ignore-submodules --); then
                s+='!';
            fi;

            # Check for untracked files.
            if [ -n "$(git ls-files --others --exclude-standard)" ]; then
                s+='?';
            fi;

            # Check for stashed files.
            if $(git rev-parse --verify refs/stash &>/dev/null); then
                s+='$';
            fi;

        fi;

        # Get the short symbolic ref.
        # If HEAD isn’t a symbolic ref, get the short SHA for the latest commit
        # Otherwise, just give up.
        branchName="$(git symbolic-ref --quiet --short HEAD 2> /dev/null || \
            git rev-parse --short HEAD 2> /dev/null || \
            echo '(unknown)')";

        [ -n "${s}" ] && s=" [${s}]";

        echo -e "${1}${branchName}${2}${s}";
    else
        return;
    fi;
}

if tput setaf 1 &> /dev/null; then
    tput sgr0; # reset colors
    bold=$(tput bold);
    reset=$(tput sgr0);
    # Solarized colors, taken from http://git.io/solarized-colors.
    black=$(tput setaf 0);
    blue=$(tput setaf 33);
    cyan=$(tput setaf 37);
    green=$(tput setaf 64);
    orange=$(tput setaf 166);
    purple=$(tput setaf 125);
    red=$(tput setaf 124);
    violet=$(tput setaf 61);
    white=$(tput setaf 15);
    yellow=$(tput setaf 136);
else
    bold='';
    reset="\e[0m";
    black="\e[1;30m";
    blue="\e[1;34m";
    cyan="\e[1;36m";
    green="\e[1;32m";
    orange="\e[1;33m";
    purple="\e[1;35m";
    red="\e[1;31m";
    violet="\e[1;35m";
    white="\e[1;37m";
    yellow="\e[1;33m";
fi;

# Highlight the user name when logged in as root.
if [[ "${USER}" == "root" ]]; then
    userStyle="${red}";
else
    userStyle="${orange}";
fi;

# Highlight the hostname when connected via SSH.
if [[ "${SSH_TTY}" ]]; then
    hostStyle="${bold}${red}";
else
    hostStyle="${yellow}";
fi;

# Set the terminal title and prompt.
PS1="\[\033]0;\W\007\]"; # working directory base name
PS1+="\[${bold}\]\n"; # newline
PS1+="\[${userStyle}\]\u"; # username
PS1+="\[${white}\] at ";
PS1+="\[${hostStyle}\]\h"; # host
PS1+="\[${white}\] in ";
PS1+="\[${green}\]\W"; # working directory path
PS1+="\$(prompt_git \"\[${white}\] on \[${violet}\]\" \"\[${blue}\]\")"; # Git repository details
PS1+="\n";
PS1+="\[${white}\]\$ \[${reset}\]"; # `$` (and reset color)
export PS1;

PS2="\[${yellow}\]→ \[${reset}\]";
export PS2;
```

Comment: Some extra information would be useful here. Your picture shows only some files in your home dir, but not all. 1) Which of the following 4 files exist: `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, `.bashrc`; 2) Does any of these 4 files source any other one? 3) Which of these 4 files (if any) explicitly sources (not executes) `.bash_prompt`?

Comment: Updated original post.

Comment: "I have a setup script which sources .bash_profile and .bash_prompt to pick up the changes."
.bash_profile should be loaded automatically. There is no need to reference it from another script.

Comment: Typically, your customized prompt would be set in ~/.bashrc. Because OS X calls `login` when you start a terminal session, you need to source `~/.bashrc` in `~/.bash_profile`. Your `.bashrc` in turn could source `.bash_prompt`.

Comment: May have done this in the wrong order, as now when I open new windows, I see `-bash: book: command not found`.

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Updated with code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tl;dr, using `source .bash_prompt` inside of `.bash_profile` works just fine and resolves the unrelated startup issue.